# Loop until user presses 'C' in sh file

Tags: bash, sh

What I want is as follows:

At first when user runs .sh file it displays following:

```
Review id:
You id is:XXX000YYY
Do you want to change it?[Press Y to change, C to continue]:
```

Now If user presses `Y` then let him change id and again show this again, and do this until user presses `C` to continue. How can I do this in shell script?

---

I tried following but don't know what to write in if conditions???

```
while :
do
  echo "Enter id:"
  read line
  echo "Your id: $line"
  echo "Do you want to change(Y to change, C to conntinue)?"
  read ans
  if [ $ans = C ] || [ $ans = c ]; then
  /// .... finish the loop
  elif [ $ans = y ] || [ $ans = Y ]; then
  /// .... continue while loop
  else
  echo "Wrong selection."
  /// .... continue while loop
  fi
exit 0
```

---

I changed it to following, but now it's in infinite loop:

```
echo "Enter id:"
read line
echo "Your id: $line"
echo "Do you want to change(Y to change, C to conntinue)?"
read ans
while [ $ans = y ] || [ $ans = Y ];:
do
  echo "Enter id:"
  read line
  echo "Your id: $line"
  echo "Do you want to change(Y to change, C to conntinue)?"
  read ans
done
```

Comment: The [Advanced BASH Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html) can help you decipher where to start

Comment: Where did he wrote condition in while statement?

Comment: I have updated question with my try. Can you help me in what to write in `if` part?

Comment: This maybe a better question for http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
while [ $ans = y ] || [ $ans = Y ];:
```

which should be

```
while [ $ans = y ] || [ $ans = Y ];
```

The issue is that the colon is a bash built-in that gets interpereted as `true`. More information at [What Is the Purpose of the `:' (colon) GNU Bash Builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin).

The following code works for me

```
#!/bin/env bash
echo "Enter id:"
read line
echo "Your id: $line"
echo "Do you want to change(Y to change, C to conntinue)?"
read ans
while [ $ans == y ] || [ $ans == Y ] ;
do
echo "ANS: ${ans}"
  echo "Enter id:"
  read line
  echo "Your id: $line"
  echo "Do you want to change(Y to change, C to conntinue)?"
  read ans
done
```

Note: it's always better to include a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the top of your scripts.